# Get deployed config from Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud

How can i get the latest config that running on the google cloud endpoints for a API?

I looking into the service management apis but i can't find anything that is related to google endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of all the configs of a service:

```
$ gcloud service-management configs list --service=[SERVICE].appspot.com
```

Then, to review the details of a single config, use the `CONFIG_ID` provided that is of interest to you:

```
$ gcloud service-management configs describe [CONFIG_ID] --service=[SERVICE].appspot.com
```

The `CONFIG_ID` currently being used will be the one referenced in your App.yaml file.

Additionally, you can always get the discovery document by visiting the following URL:

```
https://[SERVICE-dot-][ProjectId].appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/[VERSION]/apis
```